# what is the C/D equation in dsp?

Tags: dsp-core, exam

I have one example test question by this kind:

[image]

So in [this ebook](https://books.google.com/books?id=m-yFotJKIEMC&pg=PA5&dq=ebook%20digital%20system%20progress%20with%20matlab&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJhZncnuzmAhUQPewKHRRLCgMQ6AEIOzAC) (Digital Signal Processing Using MATLAB) as the DSP references and not found C/D block equations on it?

[image]

and this c/d search results?

[image]

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

C/D is simply a "continuous-to-discrete" time conversion. In other words, sampling! :-) You can use $T$ to sample your continuous time signal $x(t)$ into a discrete time signal $x[n]$. Just replace $t=nT$ in your $x(t)$ equation, to turn it into a discrete time signal $x[n]$. D/C is the opposite operation. I think you can move on from here. Let us know if you can work it out now or if you need further help.

Comment: Nice. For the record, the abbreviation is often found under "D/C Converter" or "C/D Converter", or "C-to-D"/"D-to-C" converters